# Stacked dryer washer grounding

Tags: grounding

I got a 10/3 wire for my Dryer/Washer stacked.
There is a Ground attached to the Dryer/Washer.
Can I attache the ground wire from my 10/3 directly to the ground on my Dryer/Washer?

Comment: Is it 10/3 with ground (4 conductors), or just 10/3 (3 conductors)? Is it a gas or electric dryer? What is the make and model of the units?

Answer (score 1):

A Ground is just that a Ground and should always be used. However, please be more specific: is there just one plug with the stacked units or separate individual plugs for each? Typically a 30 amp 220 volt double pole breaker needs to be installed, 30 amp plug and receptacle. Also, check the manufacturer's wiring diagram.